# Using .push() to add multiple items into an array, but only having one added - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript and learning 100% on my own via free, internet based resources. (just an intro in case my question is a silly mistake)

The problem:

> Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings.

Example

> For inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"], the output should be
>   allLongestStrings(inputArray) = ["aba", "vcd", "aba"].

My code:

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    var longest = inputArray.reduce(function (a, b) { 
        return a.length > b.length ? a : b; 
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if(inputArray[i].length === longest.length) {
            var longArray = [];
            longArray.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
        return longArray;
    }
}
```

Errors:

**Input:**
inputArray: ["aba", 
 "aa", 
 "ad", 
 "vcd", 
 "aba"]

**Output:**
["aba"]

**Expected Output:**
["aba", 
 "vcd", 
 "aba"]

**Input:**
inputArray: ["abc", 
 "eeee", 
 "abcd", 
 "dcd"]

**Output:**
null

**Expected Output:**
["eeee", 
 "abcd"]

Comment: `longArray` should be declared outside the loop or else it's reset every iteration

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks! I moved it inside the loop and still only one output. Although, the second error did change to this:

Input:
inputArray: ["abc", 
 "eeee", 
 "abcd", 
 "dcd"]
Output:
["eeee"]
Expected Output:
["eeee", 
 "abcd"]

Comment: You are also returning inside the body of the for loop. It should be moved to the bottom of the function declaration.

Comment: Summary: declare `var longArray = [];` _before_ the `for` statement, and `return longArray` _after_ the closing brace `}` of the for loop.

Comment: @StephenP hmm, I tried that and the first error remained the same, but the second error now shows: Input:
inputArray: ["abc", 
 "eeee", 
 "abcd", 
 "dcd"]
Output:
[]
Expected Output:
["eeee", 
 "abcd"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the changes described in the comments gives me:

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    var longest = inputArray.reduce(function (a, b) { 
        return a.length > b.length ? a : b; 
    });
    var longArray = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i].length === longest.length) {
            longArray.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return longArray;
}
```

In my browser console (Chrome), after declaring the function, I do

```
var inp1 = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"];
var inp2 = ["abc", "eeee", "abcd", "dcd"];
//
allLongestStrings(inp1)
allLongestStrings(inp2)
```

I get what you list as the expected output for both these cases:

```
allLongestStrings(inp1)
(3) ["aba", "vcd", "aba"]
allLongestStrings(inp2)
(2) ["eeee", "abcd"]
```

Comment: Ah! I apologize, I incorrectly moved it down only one bracket, not two. I copied your code and then pasted it under mine and compared, and that's what happened. On a side note, it worked! Thanks so much for your help!!!